# lifecycle of variable in defered lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, lifetime

I try to submit a lambda function to a thread to defer its execution. However, I face some issue with lifetime of variables passed by copy.

Here is my code

```
#include <future>
#include "ctpl_stl.h"

ctpl::thread_pool tp(2);

class T1 //a simple class that can print a number
{
public:
    void print(int number)
    {
        std::cout << a << " " << number << std::endl;
    }
    int a = 6;
};

void testPrint(T1 *t1, int number) //a function used by the lambda
{
    t1->print(number);
}

template<typename F, typename... Rest>
auto submit(F && f, Rest&&... rest) ->std::future<bool>
{
    return tp.push([&, rest...] (int id) {
        return f(id, rest...);
    });
}

void test(T1 *t1)
{
    int number = 6;
    submit(
    [=](int threadId, int number)
    {
        std::cout << threadId << std::endl;
        testPrint(t1, number);
        return true;
    },
        number);
}

int main()
{
    T1 *t1 = new T1();
    test(t1);

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);//for testing purpose
    return 0;
}
```

You can think that the code is too complex for what it does, but I have removed all unnecessary code to reproduce the error. Class T1, submit function are useless for other purposes not needed here.

When I run this code, the function testPrint, launched in a thread of the threadPool, will crash, as t1 is not a valid pointer.

I don't understand why, as t1 is passed to the lambda by copy, as the

```
[=]
```

of the lambda function specify.

So my question is: why t1 is invalid, and when the values created by copy for a lambda are created/destroyed?

Comment: Problem is with `submit` function, where `f` as local variable is being captured by reference `&`. So you have dangling reference to `f` when accessing it by `operator()` of closure is invoked.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess I can fix it by changing the lambda in submit function to take f by copy too? so with [=] instead of [&, rest...]? Is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: It depends how passed closure to `submit` function is heavy. By `[=]`, `f` is copied, why not to moved it by `[f = std::move(f),rest...]` with init-capture list (since c++14) ?

Comment: Interesting, I don't really know about std::move and its purpose. I will dig into it, but intuitively it seems nice as I suppose it transfer ownership (kind of) of f to the lambda ?

Comment: For more info you can look at [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), section *Lambda capture*.